# Why dbicdump shorten table column name in ResultSource when it reach 30 chars?

Tags: perl, schema, dbi, dbix-class, dbicdump

I dumped a MSSQL database schema using `dbicdump`:

```
dbicdump \
    -o dump_directory=./lib \
    -o components='["InflateColumn::DateTime"]' \
    -o constraint='qr/(V_A_Table_With_A_Very_Long_Name)/i' \
    -o preserve-case=1 \
    My::Package dbi:ODBC:dsn=ODBC_Conf my_username 'secret'
```

The schema got generated properly, there were no error nor warning. Though, one of the column name is called `Code_Tranche_Unite_Urbaine_XXXY` in the database, but what I got in the corresponding ResultSource is `Code_Tranche_Unite_Urbaine_XXX` (without the *Y* in the end) :

```
package My::Schema::Result::VATableWithAVeryLongName;
#...
__PACKAGE__->table("V_A_Table_With_A_Very_Long_Name");
#...
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  #...
  # Should be 'Code_Tranche_Unite_Urbaine_XXXY'
  "Code_Tranche_Unite_Urbaine_XXX",
  {
    accessor    => "code_tranche_unite_urbaine_XXX", # No 'Y' here
    data_type   => "integer",
    is_nullable => 1,
  },
  #...
);
```

I kept the generated ResultSource as is, didn't edited it. It looks like `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` shorten the column name at 30 chars. This is a supposition because i didn't manage to find any documentation about it.

If it could make any difference, `V_A_Table_With_A_Very_Long_Name` is a MSSQL view, accessed through ODBC.

I am a bit curious of the reasons why `dbicdump` would behave this way: I could say that it is because 30 chars is *really too long*, but the thing is that you don't always have the possibility to change the table schema.

Is it the behavior that is expected and if so why is it like this? Could it be a bug? Is there a way to control this?

Versions: `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` and `dbicdump` comes from the same `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` installation, `0.07049`

Comment: What version of DBIC and of the Schema Loader are you using?

Comment: @simbabque edited my question with version `0.07049`.

Comment: There's no `30` in the source at all. Must be something else. I sent your question to the maintainer of DCSL but he doesn't use SO. He said to look at what the DBI `column_info` method returns.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque , I will try this.